# Questions about the beginning of this game

Tags: opening, analysis, learning, sicilian-defense

```
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2018.12.29"]
[White "Leon_Likes_Chess"]
[Black "SmojLee"]
[Result "0-1"]
[ECO "B47"]
[WhiteElo "1625"]
[BlackElo "2310"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[EndTime "14:52:01 PST"]
[Termination "SmojLee won by resignation"]
[FEN ""]

1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 e6 5.Nc3 Qc7 6.Ndb5 Qe5 7.f4 Qb8 8.e5 a6 9.Nd6+ Bxd6 10.exd6 Nh6 11.Be2 Nf5 12.Ne4 b5 13.g4 Nh4 14.Rg1 Qb6 15.Nf2 Nd4 16.Be3 Ndf3+ 17.Bxf3 Qxe3+ 18.Be2 Nf3+ 19.Kf1 Nxh2+ 20.Kg2 Bb7+ 21.Kxh2 h5 22.gxh5 Qxf4+ 23.Rg3 Qxf2+ 24.Kh3 Qf5+ 25.Kh2 Rc8 26.Bg4 Rxc2+ 27.Be2 Qxh5+ 28.Kg1 Bf3 29.Qxc2 Qh2+ 30.Kf1 Bxe2+ 31.Qxe2 Qxg3 32.Qf2 Rh1+ 33.Ke2 Qxf2+ 34.Kxf2 Rxa1  0-1
```

This is a 20min rapid game I played with black and I have questions about the beginning of the game:

Question 1 - What was the purpose of 6.....Qe5, it looks like it loses a tempo and gives White an advantage

Question 2 - Doesn't 13.g4 weaken the White king?

Question 3 - Why 14. Rg1? White should really try to get his King to safety and focus on development

I would appreciate if someone can give me their thoughts about the rest of the game, thank you!

Comment: Good game by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What was the purpose of 6... Qe5? It looks like it loses a tempo and gives White an advantage.

I think you are asking the wrong person. You said you were playing black, so, why did you play this move? Exactly as you say, it loses a tempo and worsens your position. 6... Qb8 was much safer.

> Doesn't 13. g4 weaken the White king?

I don't think so. White has a nice setup after 13... Nh4 14. Qd3, and even has the initiative as a kingside attack is ready to be launched against the black king. However, accurate play is required:

```
[FEN "rqb1k2r/3p1ppp/p1nPp3/1p3n2/4NP2/8/PPP1B1PP/R1BQK2R w KQkq b6 0 1"]

1. g4 Nh4 2. Qd3 f5 3. gxf5 Nxf5 4. Bh5+ g6 5. Bg4 O-O
```

The bishop defends f4, so white has nothing to worry about.

> Why 14. Rg1? White should really try to get his King to safety and focus on development.

I wouldn't say Rg1 is a blunder, though, as you said, development takes precedence here. The queen must take part in the kingside action via Qd3. You can also get your king to safety - the engines agree, but it is not a humane decision to get your king walking:

```
[FEN "rqb1k2r/3p1ppp/p1nPp3/1p6/4NPPn/8/PPP1B2P/R1BQK2R w KQkq - 1 1"]

1. Kf2 (1. Kd2? Bb7 2. Qe1 Ng6 3. Kd1 Nd4 4. Bd3 O-O {and the white king ends up exposed in the middle of the board.}) f5 2. Kg3 fxe4 3. Kxh4
```

Your play was almost perfect throughout the middle game, though you missed a mate-in-4 starting at move 28 (the position was winning for black anyways):

```
[FEN "4k2r/1b1p1pp1/p2Pp3/1p5q/8/6R1/PPr1B3/R2Q2K1 b k - 1 1"]

1... Qc5+ 2. Qd4 Qxd4+ 3. Kf1 Rh1+ 4. Rg1 Rxg1#
```

Comment: I intentionally "missed" a mate in 4 since I wanted the game to last longer :)

Comment: @TheStrategyGamer Note that this is a very dangerous way of playing, and if you keep it up it will cost you points in the future. No need to prolong the ineviteable when you see the kill.